# Pik not installing latest patch level for ruby version 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pik, railsinstaller

I used RailsInstaller (for Windows) to set up my environment for my Rails 3 app.  I recently installed Pik so that I can update my ruby version as well.

According to the Pik docs https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/wiki/Usage, running 'pik install ruby 1.9.3' should install lastest version of ruby (or atleast the latest patch level for the version I am specifying).

However, this only installs ruby 1.9.3p429, but I understand that 1.9.3p545 is available.

Does anyone know how I can install 1.9.3p545?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you went with Pik from your previous question. I read on another thread that Pik only supports some of the 1.9.3 patch levels, but unfortunately nothing verifiable. The project has also been abandoned, no longer maintained, which might explain why that latest patch isn't supported...
Might just be my perspective, but seems like Windows is very poorly supported in the Rails/Ruby world? Our project requires Windows and Linux support which is causing us lots of grief. If you find a solid & reliable upgrade solution for Windows I would be very interested!